# firebase users collection has document of users with strange ID

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I;m new to firebase, I've users collection with documents, but the ID's are not know for me, I don't know how to access them, I tried with `uid` but those ID's doesn't look like `uid`s therefore It didn't work

[image: firebase Picture]

as you can see in the screenshot above, documents ids are different from users `uids` my target is to access user, after that document and add a new collection ( of course not in all users, the registered one.

any ideas how to access them?

```swift
            // create user
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, err) in
                // check for errors
                
                if let err = err {
                    // error occuried
                    showError("error while creating user")
                }else {
                    // user was created succesfully,store name and vaccine
                    let db = Firestore.firestore()
                    
                    db.collection("users").addDocument(data: ["username":self.usernameLabelRegister.text ,"vaccine":self.chosenVaccine,"nationality":self.chosenLocation, "uid":result!.user.uid,"profileImageUrl":RegisterViewController.staticProfileImageUrlString]) { error in
                        if error != nil {
                            // show error
                            showError("user data blablabla")
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Firebase Authentication does not automatically write user data to Firestore. If user data is showing up in your database, it must have been written there by part of your application (unless you've been hacked of course, in which case I recommend reading [how to secure your database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)).

Comment: As Frank mentioned, you must be writing data to Firestore explicitly. Can you update your question and add your code in it?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen updated code please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are indeed adding a document with random ID (which is not same as user's UID). Instead use `setData` where you can specify the ID:

```
// Pass user ID from result of createUser
db.collection("users").document(result.user.uid).setData(data: ["username":self.usernameLabelRegister.text ,"vaccine":self.chosenVaccine,"nationality":self.chosenLocation, "uid":result!.user.uid,"profileImageUrl":RegisterViewController.staticProfileImageUrlString]) { err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error writing document: \(err)")
    } else {
        print("Document successfully written!")
    }
}
```